# Blend Tool Smooth Color Not Working Properly

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blending-objects

I'm  having a few issues with the blend tool.  One of the biggest problems I'm seeing that when I select "Smooth Color" sometimes I get a "stepped" result.

[image]

While I understand I could switch spacings and get similar results, I'm curious as to why this is happening.  Mainly because I like to make edits after I apply the blend, so going back and switching steps or changing spacing seems a bit tedious.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because you're attempting to blend separate shapes. There is an easy work-around for this, which fools the blend tool into thinking GX graphic is one shape, vs two. All you have to do is make the GX a compound path (⌘8 on a MAC). Then drag and duplicate, select your additional color and then apply your blending with smooth color. This will create a smooth blend vs a stepped result.